# React native pie chart

Tags: javascript, react-native, pie-chart, react-native-svg-charts, victory-native

How can I draw a pie chart like this? I'm using VictoryPie and VictoryLabel from library victory-native, but I cannot set label position and background color for each label depending on the data and I cannot set the border white like that.
Is there any library that can resolve this?

[image: this is the chart in design]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think a version of what you want can be achieved via victor-native just put your data like this:

```
data: [
{ y: 50, x: '50%'},
{ y: 20, x: '20%'},
{ y: 10, x: '10%'},
{ y: 15, x: '15%'},
{ y: 5, x: '5%'},
],
```

Check out [this](https://swairaq.medium.com/react-native-donut-pie-chart-cdb25767b4f9) medium on piecharts